# Firebase get child name by value and remove it

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

My JSON looks like this:

```
users
  username1: "WWOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2"
  username2: "RJ6PztTLmsg222oUygWHtWpVHdg1"
```

I would like to get "username1" by their key which is (auth.uid)! and if its found i want to delete it, So after delete it will be looks like this:

```
    users
  username2: "RJ6PztTLmsg222oUygWHtWpVHdg1"
```

.

```
self.ref.child("users").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: user?.uid).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                            if snapshot.exists() {

                                print("\(snapshot.value)")
                                snapshot.ref.child(snapshot.value as! String).removeValue() // this deleting every thing which is WRONG!



                            } else{

                                print("Not found--")

                            }
                            self.ref.removeAllObservers()
                        })
                    }
```

This code deleting everything in users. I just want to delete specific user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, my approach is if I want to query 1 value at 1 moment, like you are doing, I do a observeSingleEvent (is this the best approach?). But to solve your problem, you forgot to add your "users" path. Below code is more safe to use, since you force unwrap (which is not recommend for this case):

```
let dataRef = self.ref.child("users")
dataRef.keepSynced(true)
       if let usersUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
    dataRef.child("users").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: usersUID).observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
       let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       for (key, value) in values{
       print(value) // does this print the uid?
       print(key) // or this one?

            self.ref.child("users/\(key)").removeValueWithCompletionBlock({ (err, ref) in
                if err != nil {
                    print(err)
                } else {
                    print(ref)
                    print("Removed")
                }
            })
        }
    })
    }
```

Try to add this, right after the print(snapshot)

Comment: Thanks! but could you show how could i use "observeSingleEvent" at this case? Edit your answer with full code it will be appreciated and accepted

Comment: @Sam I updated it, it should work although I did not tested it

Comment: I got confused, If you could explain what happening here please https://i.gyazo.com/15dc03d6245cad3114120a680e422734.png I've mention what is going on in the photo. Any idea?

Comment: @Sam Whoops. One very common mistake is when using a observeSingleEvent to keep your database in Sync. I edit the code in a minute

Comment: @Sam Can you check the print is now correct (the user exists in the database)? If it is good, I make one last change to make it work because I think you need to loop through the data again.

Comment: Thanks! Yes now its correct, but the other code starts with "if let username" it seems not running

Comment: @Sam Check the code I added, does the key appears there where you want it to be? Then you can remove the value from the key/value inside that loop

Comment: No print(value) printed the key "WOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2"

Comment: @Sam What did "key" print? Nothing??

Comment: Yes, print(key) printed the username, so we need to remove the child now, how could it be

Comment: @Sam well just pass key instead of username, see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, It works great now, I hope you'll get success in your whole life.